# How to develop applications for windows or bada using phonegap and eclipse plugin?

Tags: eclipse, cordova, symbian, bada, tizen

I have installed eclipse phonegap plugin and I am easily able to make applications for android. However I want to make application for any other platform like bada, tizen , blackberry, etc. But when I create new Phonegap project, it doesn't show any option for choosing platform. It directly takes me  to android. Is there any way that I can use this plugin for developing for other platforms.

I have googled a lot but nothing found relevant.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you may be interested in Titanium. Latest version supports (check beta) Tizen and Blackberry 10 as well as Android and iPhone. With it you will be able use javascript for mobile application development. Also it creates "native" application  instead of html if possible.
And forgot Bada. It`s gone.